# React w Gatsby: implemented sequential fade-in animation for gallery but it doesn't work right after being deployed

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gatsby

The source code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-nvhl7

And the deployed site is here: https://csb-nvhl7-24q4bchuz.now.sh/

The effect I am trying to achieve is simple and straightforward.

First I used this query to load all the image files from the `images` folder

```
const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allFile(
        filter: {
          extension: { regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/" }
          sourceInstanceName: { eq: "images" }
        }
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(maxWidth: 800, quality: 95) {
                aspectRatio
                src
                srcSet
                originalName
                srcWebp
                srcSetWebp
                sizes
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Then I have a `gallery` component to display them by dividing these images into three groups, and we can use `project1`, `project2` and `project3` to navigate between them.

```
const Gallery = ({ minWidth }) => {
  let refs = {}

  const allPics = Image().map(({ childImageSharp }, i) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    refs[i] = useRef(null)
    childImageSharp.index = i
    return childImageSharp
  })

  const firsload = allPics.slice(0, 5)
  const secload = allPics.slice(5, 10)
  const third = allPics.slice(10)

  const [imgs, setImgs] = useState(firsload)

  const thumbnails = imgs.map(img => img.fluid.srcSet.split(" ")[0])

  return (
    <>
      <ProjectsContainer>
        <Project
          onClick={() => {
            setImgs(firsload)
          }}
        >
          Project 1.
        </Project>
        <Project
          onClick={() => {
            setImgs(secload)
          }}
        >
          Project 2.
        </Project>
        <Project
          onClick={() => {
            setImgs(third)
          }}
        >
          Project 3.
        </Project>
      </ProjectsContainer>
      <Mansory gap={"0em"} minWidth={minWidth}>
        {imgs.map((img, i) => {
          return (
            <PicContainer key={img.index}>
              <Enlarger
                src={thumbnails[i]}
                enlargedSrc={img.fluid.src}
                index={img.index}
                orderIndex={i}
                onLoad={() => {
                  refs[img.index].current.toggleOpacity(1) <-- use ref to keep track of every Enlarger 
                }}
                ref={refs[img.index]}
              />
            </PicContainer>
          )
        })}
      </Mansory>
    </>
  )
}
```

For every `Enlarger` that gets rendered by the `Gallery`, they are a zoom image component

```
import Img from "react-image-enlarger"

class Enlarger extends React.Component {
  state = { zoomed: false, opacity: 0 } <--- initially every image's opacity is 0, then it shows up by being toggled opacity 1

  toggleOpacity = o => {
    this.setState({ opacity: o })
  }

  render() {
    const { index, orderIndex, src, enlargedSrc, onLoad } = this.props
    return (
      <div style={{ margin: "0.25rem" }} onLoad={onLoad}> <-- where we toggle the opacity when the element is onloaded
        <Img
          style={{
            opacity: this.state.opacity,
            transition: "opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25,0.46,0.45,0.94)",
            transitionDelay: `${orderIndex * 0.07}s`,
          }}
          zoomed={this.state.zoomed}
          src={src}
          enlargedSrc={enlargedSrc}
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ zoomed: true })
          }}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            this.setState({ zoomed: false })
          }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And I have made it clear in the code snippet where I implemented the sequential fade-in animation by using `ref` to control every `Enlarger`'s `toggleOpacity` method.

This code works great on localhost, i.e. during development. You can try the codesandbox link above to see it. However the bug appears **only when the page is deployed.**. Click on the deployed version (https://csb-nvhl7-24q4bchuz.now.sh/) you can see that when browser first loading the page, some pictures are missing, because their opacity are still 0, which I suspect is because `refs[img.index].current.toggleOpacity(1)` somehow didn't get called on the image when they are onloaded. However the weird thing is, **when you navigate between the projects**, there's no problems at all with this animation and opacity change, they are normal. And when you refresh the page, the problem shows up again.

I been struggling with this problem for days and couldn't figure out why. Also although here I used ZEIT Now to deploy the site, the problem didn't go away when I used Netlify to deploy.

Comment: sounds like an issue with server side rendering (`onLoad` is probably not executed). see if any [SSR APIs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/) can help

Answer (score 2):

Its not because of deployment, in Production Your images taking more time to load. See the image network call in the browser

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kishore's answer, you may want make your query after the page loaded (maybe in componentDidMount) and use setState to trigger react to re-render once that content has been fully loaded.